# Django geting request in signal post_save

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-signals, django-middleware

I am trying to access Django built-in `request` to get some important data and most of them coming through my custom middleware, that is why i need to access the `request` at any means.

this is my signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def create_journal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # request.finance_data
        # Do something
```

But there is no argument like `request` so I need to extend whatever needed to get `request` here..

in the request, I have finance_data and I access that like this: `request.finance_data`

I know i can access it from view but my case will not solve in view, i need to access it in signal at any means

Can anyone help me please to get this?

Comment: If you need access to the request, the signal is not the appropriate place for whatever you're doing. Do it in the view

Comment: I know i can get it in view but my case is different, i need to access request in signal at any means

Comment: I have the same question